# Is there a wireframing tool for web apps that can re-use my own custom CSS?

Tags: css, wireframe

I have been searching for and have not located (I fear it doesn't exist) a wire frame application that will use our current css for objects.

We have spent a lot of time perfecting our css to get the look we want, now I want to be able to use that css for new mockups without creating new objects each time we add something (as we would have to in photoshop).

In a perfect world, it would even handle the page layout so all that remains is the logic.

Has anyone heard of a tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it, and I can't vouch for it, but https://alpha.easel.io/ might fit the bill. It's still in beta, but looks very interesting.

From their homepage: "Implement designs quickly using exact CSS properties rather than guessing from a mockup."

Comment: This looks like it would work.  I have requested a beta invite, but it may be just what I want.  Thanks!!

Comment: I have been testing the application.  It is definitely a beta, but has potential.  However, it does not allow me to upload my own css.  I have to build the objects there and then get the resulting css for coding.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting to know. Thanks for posting your experience with the app.

Comment: I have since learned that with a paid subscription, I can upload my own css.  I haven't tried it yet because they need to develop it more before I will pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

http://axure.com is a popular wireframing tool. There ways to make it use custom CSS: http://enterpriseux.tumblr.com/post/8972215862/an-axure-html-prototype-hack

Comment: I searched the axure site and it appears that I cannot import or use my css.  I would have to recreate all objects in the custom widgets.  That could work, but isn't exactly what I am looking for.  It would probably be even faster for me to have a page with all my objects, take a screen shot and import to photoshop.

Comment: I don't have axure to test this, but from the link, I gather you were suggesting to modify the created css file.  Has anyone tried that with extensive options?  If so, how did it work?  Are you limited only by css?